# Javascript Serialization Object Like PHP's serialize()

Tags: javascript, php, serialization

I have read some explanations how to serialize JavaScript object to JSON.

Yet, I'm still wondering if there any pure Javascript function to do serialization with the same output as PHP serialize() does, not JSON.

Comment: Not as far as I know. `serialize` is specific to PHP, not a standard format.

Comment: No. [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) uses an internal *binary-string* format specific to PHP. Just make the PHP work with JSON. It'll also be more portable. Win-win. (Normal JSON looses object *types*, but there are some meta-JSON formats.)